# Visual studio 2013 crash when editing a css file. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: css, visual-studio

My installation of  vs2013 update 2 has recently started crashing whenever I try to edit a css file. I  can open the css file but the second I add/edit/delete VS crashes and restarts.

I am assuming that I have a misbehaving extension or tool but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot and figure out which one.

Logging is not showing any sort of obvious error.

This only happens with one specific project.

Comment: Does this happen (for that specific project) when running VS in safe mode?

Comment: I also tested by creating a new CSS file and adding some rules to it. That did not crash. But when I opened one of the existing ones it crashed again.

Comment: In safe mode VS does not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be the latest update to Mexedge Stylesheet Extension. Uninstalled and all works well.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There was an imcompatiblity issue between the extension and the update 2 of Visual Studio. The extension has been since updated. The new version supports less.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line to your web.config file (in appSettings node):

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```